# Botão agrupado em um field está saindo fora dos limites e sobrepondo o campo próximo a ele

Tags: css, html5, css3

Saudações a todos!

Estou usando um tema chamado remark que contém muitos elementos prontos. Estou usando uma caixa de pesquisa que contém um field do tipo texto e um botão de forma agrupada ao field.

O problema é que o botão parece não obedecer e acompanhar o field. Ele avança para o campo ao lado e não respeita a especificação de "col-md-3" que parece estar sendo válida apenas para o field e por isso, o botão parece ficar de fora.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label asp-for="CodigoPostal" class="control-label">Código Postal</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input id="txt-pessoa-endereco-codigo-postal" type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="CodigoPostal" placeholder="Digite aqui...">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button id="btn-pessoa-endereco-pesquisar-codigo-postal" type="button" class="btn btn-success" title="Pesquisar Código Postal"><i class="icon wb-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </span>
        </div>
        <span asp-validation-for="CodigoPostal" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <label asp-for="Logradouro" class="control-label">Logradouro</label>
        <input type="text" asp-for="Logradouro" id="txt-pessoa-endereco-logradouro" class="form-control text-uppercase" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Logradouro" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Alguém sabe como corrigir o posicionamento do botão para ele respeitar o posicionamento correto, sem afetar o campo ao lado?

Obserigado :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

tudo bem? Então você não colocou seu css, então resolvi baseado nesse seu código.

```css
#logadouro, #codpos{ 
display:inline-flex;  
position:relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Background animado in text</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/background%20text%20animado.css">
</head>
<body> 
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row form-group "> 
 
    <div id="codpos"class="col-md-7">
        <label asp-for="CodigoPostal" class="control-label">Código Postal</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input id="txt-pessoa-endereco-codigo-postal" type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="CodigoPostal" placeholder="Digite aqui...">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                
              <button type="button" id="pessoa-endereco-pesquisar-codigo-postal"  class="btn btn-success">Pesquisar Código Postal</button>
            </span>
        </div>
        <span asp-validation-for="CodigoPostal" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="logadouro" class="col-md-5">
        <label asp-for="Logradouro" class="control-label">Logradouro</label>
        <input type="text" asp-for="Logradouro" id="txt-pessoa-endereco-logradouro" class="form-control text-uppercase" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Logradouro" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Espero ter ajudado, qual duvida basta falar.

Comment: Obrigado @Rodrigo Almeida Bezerra! :)